# View into remote database with error tolerance

Tags: sql-server, error-handling, sql-view

I have a view in MSSQL into a remote database that looks like

```sql
create view product_configurations as
    select item_num, items_per_bundle, bundle_per_pallet from [12.34.56.78].[database].[schema].[product_configuration]
```

Is there a way, wholely within the View, to make it default to a different backup table (say `product_configuration_backup`) in my local database if the remote database fails for any reason?

I've tried

```sql
create view my_product_copnfiguration as
    if OBJECT_ID('[12.34.56.78].[database].[schema].[product_configuration]') is not null
        select item_num, items_per_bundle, bundle_per_pallet from [12.34.56.78].[database].[schema].[product_configuration]
    else
        select item_num, items_per_bundle, bundle_per_pallet from backup_product_configuration
```

but SQL server complains about "Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'if'."

Comment: Not within the `VIEW`, no. A `VIEW` is just a pseudo table's who's definition is defined by a single `SELECT` statement. It can't have logic like an `IF` statement in it; you would have to perform the logic outside of the `VIEW`. Alternatively you could use a stored procedure, but note that these do not operator like a `VIEW`; you wouldn't be able to reference it a your `SELECT`, for example.

Comment: object_id cannot be used with a four-part name - so your current approach is a dead-end. Generally speaking, you may find the concept of testing at query execution time to be unworkable (unbearable might be better word) since there is no quick way of determining that your linked server (and database object object) can be reached. A connection must be attempted and you suffer from the delay when it cannot be reached. There are no easy solutions since much depends on your goal and your desire for timeliness vs. accuracy.

Comment: Given the table name, I can guess that this table doesn't really change much - maybe not even used much. Pushing the changes from the source (linked server) would be a more robust solution. Alternatively, pull the table on some periodic basis. Your queries would only refer to the local table. Regardless of approach, you might want to consider how anyone can know if "current" information is available (or used by a query) or if the "stale" backup information was used - if that is important.

Answer (score 0):

Views can only contain a single `SELECT` statement. If you wish to include more complex scripting, you will need to add it to a separate script, perhaps a stored procedure. You may be able reference the results of the stored procedure without too much change to the calling scripts - your `IF` statement, should work fine in a stored procedure.

```
CREATE PROC [dbo].[GET_Product_Configuration]
AS
if OBJECT_ID('[12.34.56.78].[database].[schema].[product_configuration]') is not null
    select item_num, items_per_bundle, bundle_per_pallet from [12.34.56.78].[database].[schema].[product_configuration]
else
    select item_num, items_per_bundle, bundle_per_pallet from  backup_product_configuration
```